# Reading http request from socket with null check java

Tags: java, inputstream, findbugs

I'm reading HTTP request from socket input stream

```
StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder();
String inputLine;
while (!(inputLine = in.readLine()).equals("")) {
    request.append(inputLine + "\r\n");
}
```

It's working but `findbugs` gives the following bug: `Dereference of the result of readLine() without nullcheck`. Request ends with `""` not `eof`. So how can I check null value here?

Comment: as a rule of thumb you should use equals check like `("").equals(in.readLine())` this because you know ("") will never be null thus no null pointer exception chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like that:

```
 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
```

But I assume that you don't want a blank string, use apache commons:

```
while(StringUtils.isNotBlank(inputLine = in.readLine())) {
```

Edit:

Also +1 for sodium's comment. However in my opinion this:

```
("").equals(in.readLine())
```

is a bit unreadable.